# Level 15 (exceptionalCrossing.js)?

Tags: untrusted

I'm stuck on Level 15 of Untrusted.

I've gotten this far with no actual knowledge of Javascript beyond knowing C and assuming things are the same. I see no possible solution to this puzzle without some trick of the language I don't know about- no matter what I put in there, player.killedBy() is going to be called, and the Professor is going to die.

Any hints?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can put anything in there that doesn't exist. eg

```
player.killedBy(nothing);
```

When you go in the water it will then throw an error message because `nothing` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 8):

Actually you can pass the level without throwing any exception, just hacking the code:

> *[line 32]*
>  player.killedBy('
>  **');},'onCollision':function(player){map.getWidth(**
>  );
>
>  Just replacing the "onCollision" action again with a function that doesn't do anything.
>
>  [image]

Then you can walk on water!!

Comment: I hate that I love your solution. Congratulations for the ingenuity.

Answer (score 3):

You can use concatenation and short circuit the collision detection routine i.e.

```
map.defineObject('water', {
    'symbol': '░',
    'color': '#44f',
    'onCollision': function (player) {
        player.killedBy(''+map.placePlayer(1,1));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Of course, the hint is in the name.

You've got to throw an exception.

Comment: But how? This answer is kinda useless without some instructions, don't you think?

Comment: I was intending it as more of a hint.

Answer (score 2):

I like this way:

```
player.killedBy(function() { throw 'I am Jesus';} ());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't acrossing water, but you can pick it up.

```
map.defineObject('water', {
        'symbol': '░',
        'color': '#44f',
        'onCollision': function (player) {
            player.killedBy();},'type':'item','beha':function(me){me.move('up');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

also u can use infinite recursion..

player.killedBy((function(){x=function(){x();};x();})());